# matplotlib: plot and get_color?

Tags: colors, matplotlib

Is it possible to get a list of colors used in a plot? 
Consider this example:

```
line1 = ax1.plot(x1,y1)
line2 = ax1.plot(x2,y2)
```

I now how to set the color

```
plt.setp(line1,'color','red')
plt.setp(line2,'color','red')
```

but is there a way how to learn what color has been used? plt.getp(line1,'color') does not work and complains that

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_color'
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OK, found an answer: The plot() call returns a list of lines. The correct way to query the color is

```
print line1[0].get_color()
```